# how to put images into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to create a slideshow. I have images inside of a div (currently p tags for testing) and I want to retrieve them with jquery and create an array. 
I want to start off by saying that I am relatively new to jQuery and I am learning as I go.

I am having trouble retrieving the images (currently p tags for testing). When I log everything in run the code I realized that the array is stored only in the first index of my array. 
This is my code so far for putting my images into an array:
My goal is to try and have each image in its own index, so I can access it easier and cycle it on my web page.

```
var img =  $('#gallery').children().each(function(){
      return this.html;
    }).get();
    var slideshow = new Array();
    slideshow.push(img);
    console.log(slideshow[0]);
    console.log(slideshow[0].length);
```

This is my html:

```
        <div id="gallery">
         <p>fsdf</p>
         <p>fsdf</p>
          <p>fsdf</p>
       </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can u put in the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array of the children of `#gallery` using jQuery, you can just do:

```
var slideshow = $('#gallery').children().get();
```

`$('#gallery').children()` creates a jQuery collection of all the children of `#gallery`.  Then, calling `.get()` on it, gets a DOM array from the jQuery collection which is all you seem to be after.

---

Or, if your HTML really looks like this in the real page:

```
   <div id="gallery">
     <img src="xyz.jpg">
     <img src="abc.jpg">
     <img src="def.jpg">
   </div>
```

and you just want the array of image objects, you can do this:

```
var slideshow = $("#gallery img").get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the arra of image objects you can use the `get();` function in jquery.

```
var slideshow = $("#the_id").get();
```

See the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var arr = $.makeArray($("#gallery *"));
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/jhph8/

See

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

http://api.jquery.com/Types/

Answer (score -1):

Jquery `children()` is used to find the innerElements of the Selector. `.each()` is used to iterate for all Element. `index` parameter is same as i in for loop. it gives which Element is this.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6AP2v/)

```
 var slideshow = new Array();
 var img =  $('#gallery').children().each(function(index,img){
   slideshow.push(img);
});
```

Comment: That's great and all, but if the OP is new to JS, it'd be a much better answer if you actually explained what's happening and why it's working.

Comment: what's the point of doing this when `$('#gallery').children()` already has `length=3` and contains array of the elements?

Answer (score -1):

```
var children = [].slice.call($('#gallery').children());
```

`children` will be the desired array.

`$('#gallery')` will return the `div` with `id` as `gallery`.
`$('#gallery').children()` will return a `collection` of the `children` of `element` with `id` as `gallery`

`[].slice.call()` will convert the `collection` to an `array`.

Comment: `$('#gallery').children()` does not return a `nodeList`, it's a jQuery collection.  You're on the wrong track here.  What you probably want is `.get()` which will get a DOM array from a jQuery collection.